# Why do frame calls take a `Vec` parameter instead of `BoundedVec`?

Tags: frame

I saw that some of the calls in `frame` take `Vec` as a parameter. I haven't found a call that takes `BoundedVec`, but my impression was that I should basically always use `BoundedVec` over `Vec`?

Comment: This depends very  much on the context it is used. Perhaps provide a few examples to reference?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. `BoundedVec` is still a relatively new type that was introduced in the last months. It is not yet used everywhere.
2. `BoundedVec` is mainly useful for when you want to make your storage bound to some maximum number of elements. A call should already by bound by a proper fee model. Meaning if someone wants to send you 1MB of data in one call, they need to pay for it. `BoundedVec` doesn't make that much sense there. However, if you want to have a static upper bound, then you can for sure also use `BoundedVec` as a parameter.